# A* Pathfinder variant not allowing movement to certain tiles

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a grid that is traversable by a character.

The grid is created by an array of [Int] shown below:

```
let tiles = [
    [(0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2)],
    [(0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1)],
    [(0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2)],
    [(0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1)],
    [(0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (2,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2)],
    [(0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1)],
    [(0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2)],
    [(0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1)],
    [(0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2)],
    [(0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1), (0,2), (0,1)]
]
```

I am then using this traversableTiles() function to find the tiles that the character can move to.  In this case a first int of 0 in the arrays entered into tiles represents a traversable tile.

```
func traversableTiles() -> [[Int]] {

    var tTiles = [[Int]]()

    func binarize(num:Int) ->Int {
        if (num == 1) {
            return Global.tilePath.nonTraversable
        } else {
            return Global.tilePath.traversable
        }
    }

    for i in 0..<tiles.count {
        let tt = tiles[i].map{i in binarize(i.0)}
        tTiles.append(tt)
    }

    return tTiles
}
```

And here is the entire Global struct:

```
struct Global {
struct tilePath {
    static let traversable = 0
    static let nonTraversable = 1
}
}
```

When told to move to to any tile that is not the FIRST ROW or LAST COLUMN the character will move properly using the A* Pathfinder class below.  When a tile on either of these locations is selected, nothing happens.  Is there a reason the character thinks it cannot move to these tiles?

```
class PathFinder {

let moveCostHorizontalOrVertical = 10
let moveCostDiagonal = 14

var iniX:Int
var iniY:Int
var finX:Int
var finY:Int
var level:[[Int]]
var openList:[String: PathNode]
var closedList:[String: PathNode]
var path = [CGPoint]()

init(xIni:Int, yIni:Int, xFin:Int, yFin:Int, lvlData:[[Int]]) {

    iniX = xIni
    iniY = yIni
    finX = xFin
    finY = yFin
    level = lvlData
    openList = [String: PathNode]()
    closedList = [String: PathNode]()
    path = [CGPoint]()

    //invert y coordinates - pre conversion (spriteKit inverted coordinate system). This PathFnding code ONLY works with positive (absolute) values

    iniY = -iniY
    finY = -finY

    //first node is the starting point

    let node:PathNode = PathNode(xPos: iniX, yPos: iniY, gVal: 0, hVal: 0, link: nil)

    //use the x and y values as a string for the dictionary key

    openList[String(iniX)+" "+String(iniY)] = node;

}
func findPath() -> [CGPoint] {

    searchLevel()

    //invert y cordinates - post conversion

    let pathWithYInversionRestored = path.map({i in i * CGPoint(x:1, y:-1)})
    return pathWithYInversionRestored.reverse()
}
func searchLevel() {

    var curNode:PathNode?
    var endNode:PathNode?
    var lowF = 100000
    var finished:Bool = false

    for obj in openList {

        let curF = obj.1.g + obj.1.h

        //currently this is just a brute force loop through every item in the list
        //can be sped up using a sorted list or binary heap, described http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/binaryHeaps.htm
        //example http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/2005/04/mazeChaser.php

        if (lowF > curF) {
            lowF = curF
            curNode = obj.1
        }

    }


    if (curNode == nil) {

        //no path exists!
        return

    } else {

        //move selected node from open to closed list

        let listKey = String(curNode!.x)+" "+String(curNode!.y)

        openList[listKey] = nil
        closedList[listKey] = curNode

        //check target

        if ((curNode!.x == finX) && (curNode!.y == finY)) {
            endNode = curNode!
            finished = true
        }

        //check each of the 8 adjacent squares

        for i in -1..<2 {
            for j in -1..<2 {

                let col = curNode!.x + i;
                let row = curNode!.y + j;

                //make sure on the grid and not current node

                if ((col >= 0 && col < level[0].count)
                    && (row >= 0 && row < level.count)
                    && (i != 0 || j != 0))
                {

                    //if traversable, not on closed list, and not already on open list - add to open list

                    let listKey = String(col)+" "+String(row)

                    if ((level[row][col] == Global.tilePath.traversable)
                        && (closedList[listKey] == nil)
                        && (openList[listKey] == nil))
                    {

                        //prevent cutting corners on diagonal movement

                        var moveIsAllowed = true

                        if ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) {
                            //is diagonal move

                            if ((i == -1) && (j == -1)) {
                                //is top-left, check left and top nodes
                                if (level[row][col+1] != Global.tilePath.traversable //top
                                    || level[row+1][col] != Global.tilePath.traversable //left
                                    ) {
                                    moveIsAllowed = false
                                }

                            } else if ((i == 1) && (j == -1)) {
                                //is top-right, check top and right nodes
                                if (level[row][col-1] != Global.tilePath.traversable //top
                                    || level[row+1][col] != Global.tilePath.traversable //right
                                    ) {
                                    moveIsAllowed = false
                                }
                            } else if ((i == -1) && (j == 1)) {
                                //is bottom-left,check bottom and left nodes
                                if (level[row][col+1] != Global.tilePath.traversable //bottom
                                    || level[row-1][col] != Global.tilePath.traversable //left
                                    ) {
                                    moveIsAllowed = false
                                }
                            } else if ((i == 1) && (j == 1)) {
                                //is bottom-right, check bottom and right nodes
                                if (level[row][col-1] != Global.tilePath.traversable //bottom
                                    || level[row-1][col] != Global.tilePath.traversable //right
                                    ) {
                                    moveIsAllowed = false
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        if (moveIsAllowed) {

                            //determine g
                            var g:Int
                            if ((i != 0) && (j != 0)) {
                                //is diagonal move
                                g = moveCostDiagonal

                            } else {
                                //is horizontal or vertical move
                                g = moveCostHorizontalOrVertical
                            }

                            //calculate h (heuristic)
                            let h = heuristic(row, col: col)

                            //create node and add to openList
                            openList[listKey] = PathNode(xPos: col, yPos: row, gVal: g, hVal: h, link: curNode)

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if (finished == false) {
            searchLevel();
        } else {
            retracePath(endNode!)
        }

    }
}

// Calculate heuristic

//Diagonal Shortcut method (slightly more expensive but more accurate than Manhattan method)
//Read more on heuristics here: http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/heuristics.htm

func heuristic(row:Int, col:Int) -> Int {
    let xDistance = abs(col - finX)
    let yDistance = abs(row - finY)
    if (xDistance > yDistance) {
        return moveCostDiagonal*yDistance + moveCostHorizontalOrVertical*(xDistance-yDistance)
    } else {
        return moveCostDiagonal*xDistance + moveCostHorizontalOrVertical*(yDistance-xDistance)
    }
}

func retracePath(node:PathNode) {

    let step = CGPoint(x: node.x, y: node.y)
    path.append(step)

    if (node.g > 0) {
        retracePath(node.parentNode!);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to get the specific issue that you are seeing; it's not clear what the question is here.

Comment: The question was edited.